# FLEX DataGrid Column Modification

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I am new in Flex. I want to display data in attached grid format. I found best way to display in DataGrid. But the CIs column has multiple entries so because of that other columns will duplicate. I want to avoid duplicate data in other columns. Attached screenshot is of excel, i want to achieve same format in Flex. I am using Flex 4.5

[image: My Requirement]

Answer (score 2):

Best way I see to do what you want is to create a custom item renderer for the CLS column and have it render as a list control. That way, the CLS item in each row will only take up one row instead of multiple rows.

Comment: this is a good call, the data just needs to be setup so that one of the properties for the data elements in the dataprovider and subsequently passed into the renderers should contain the list/array of CIs having already grouped by the other columns to obtain the list

Comment: Thanks Dom, But my objective to achieve in attached snapshot format. The snapshot i attached is on excl. Let me rephrase My Q. I want to display 'Name' , 'Address', ' Contact' and 'orders'. Now one person can place N no of orders so in order field their will be a multipal entries. I want to show all details in grid format and same time i want to avoid duplicate row for 'name','address', ' 'Contact'.

Comment: My example will still work just fine but you will need to do some more work before you put the data into the datagrid. From your dataProvider, add the first element to an arrayCollection. Then on the subsequent records of the dataProvider, check to see if the name is already in your arrayCollection. If it is, just add their order to the orders arrayCollection inside of your main arrayCollection. This will result in an arrayCollection containing people, their addresses, and contacts and each person will have one arrayCollection with their orderNumbers. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can get some idea by following code... you can build logic using below concept for your implementation. Below example is sample not complete according to your requirement: -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.core.UIComponent;
            import mx.events.AdvancedDataGridEvent;
            import mx.events.ListEvent;

            [Bindable]
            private var dpHierarchy:ArrayCollection= new ArrayCollection
                ([
                    {name:"Barbara Jennings", address: "Arizona", contact:999970, orders:["1"]},
                    {name:"Dana Binn", address: "Arizona", contact:9999130, orders:["2"]},
                    {name:"Joe Smith", address: "California", contact:9992929, orders:["3"]},
                    {name:"Alice Treu", address: "California", contact:9999230, orders:["4"]}
                ]);                    

            private function addOrder():void
            {
                for(var i:int = 0 ; i < dpHierarchy.length; i++)
                {
                    if(dropDownID.selectedItem.name == dpHierarchy[i].name)
                    {
                        var itemUpdated:Array = dpHierarchy[i].orders;
                        itemUpdated.push(orderNumber.text);
                        dpHierarchy[i].orders = itemUpdated;
                        dpHierarchy.itemUpdated(dpHierarchy[i]);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:VBox x="30" y="30" width="450" height="400">
        <s:HGroup>
            <s:Button label="Add Order" click="addOrder()"/>
            <s:DropDownList id="dropDownID" dataProvider="{dpHierarchy}" labelField="name" selectedIndex="0"/>
            <s:TextInput id="orderNumber" width="100"/>
        </s:HGroup>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="myADG"   
                             dataProvider="{dpHierarchy}"
                             variableRowHeight="true" wordWrap="true">
            <mx:columns>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="name" headerText="Name"/>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="address" headerText="Address"/>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="contact" headerText="Contact"/>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="orders" headerText="Orders" itemRenderer="OrderItemRenderer"/>

            </mx:columns>   
        </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
    </mx:VBox>  
</s:Application>
```

Item Reenderer Name: - OrderItemRenderer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:MXAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                                  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                                  xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                                  focusEnabled="true" width="90%" height="90%">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            [Bindable]
            private var initDG:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

            override public function set data(value:Object):void
            {
                super.data = value;
                initDG = new ArrayCollection(value.orders)
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:DataGrid id="dataGrid" dataProvider="{initDG}" headerHeight="0" rowCount="{initDG.length}"/>
</s:MXAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer>
```